# Merge [gpt] and [openai-gp]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [gpt](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpt) and [openai-gpt](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openai-gpt) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

```
updating post history, 73 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 73 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 71 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'openai-gpt': [openai-gpt] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 73
tag remapping of [gpt] and [openai-gpt] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
5 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```